# What is the meaning of this expression "Every time you do this a puppy dies"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I see a lot of sentences that talk about puppies dying when you do something. For instance, in the CS domain, there's a common quote which says “Every time you log in production, a puppy dies.”. What does this exactly mean ?

Comment: It's a joke.  "A puppy dies" is a sad thing.

Comment: It means don’t log in production (unless a [figurative] puppy’s death on your conscience is worth it)

Comment: @HotLicks Many thanks for your comment. Got it now

Comment: @KristinaLopez Many thanks for your comment. Got it now

Comment: It's a device used to induce guilt to prevent something from happening.  It probably evolved from something similar to "when you lie, angels/Jesus cries" - things that parents tell their kids so that develop a sense of moral ethic about certain actions .  Now, there are all sorts of similar sayings - usually having to do with cute animals (puppies, kittens, bunnies, pandas etc).  For some odd reason, many of the memes are engineering/math related.

Comment: The original admonition was that "every time you waste a piece of paper, a tree dies," which though vastly exaggerated makes some ecological sense. Puppy replaced paper as a hip joke. The joker knows that his audience is familiar with the original and wants to disrupt their complacency. It caught on.

Answer (score 2):

The specific usage is a dark twist on the often-quoted line from *It's a Wonderful Life*, "Every time a bell rings / An angel gets his wings". In this case, "every time you do X, something horrible happens".

The horrible consequence of ill-considered action ("a puppy dies") is a fairly common internet meme which probably derives from the cover image of the ["Death" issue of National Lampoon magazine](https://medium.com/@Marcos_El_Malo/the-cover-of-national-lampoons-death-issue-1224472210f9) (January 1973).